# Distinguish users with same first and last names

Tags: database

If each First/Last name pair is mapped to a unique user ID, how can I get the correct user ID when a user has the same First and Last names.

For example:

```
User ID     First Name      Last Name
123         Bob             Moore
321         Bob             Moore
```

When `Bob Moore` tries to login, how can my system determine which `Bob Moore` it is?

Thanks.

Ps. I know this is probably a frequent question, but I couldn't find a short and informative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need to always use the User ID field.  In other database structures/tables, if you want to join, you have to use User ID.

Never try to do the lookup based on first name/last name.

EDIT:
For logging in, you need things that are unique to distinguish between users.  This is usually a login name, and most sites these days use email address.

Comment: OK, I basically just wanted to confirm before telling myself that it was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will need to use a unique key to identify between the different Bob Moores. If there is nothing in your data schema that can do that, use an artifical key, such as an AUTO_INCREMENTing primary key.